# Вызов viewWillAppear и добавление в таблицу addSubView:view

Tags: ios, uitableview

Не хотелось бы разбивать на два вопроса, попробую задать их здесь:
1) Не мог бы кто-нибудь объяснить причину не вызывания viewWillAppear: Пользователь открывает модальное окно, с этого модально окна делается [self.navigationController pushViewController ..] и открывшемся контроллере уже не вызывается viewWillAppear. Я понимаю, что с модального окна не очень делать такие действия, как pushViewController, но все же почему нет вызова метода и как можно избавиться от этой проблемы?

Пример:
Мы вызвали модальный контроллер и сейчас находимся на нем. Есть кнопка:

```
- (IBAction)tapOnButton:(id)sender {        
    UserViewController *userViewController = (UserViewController *)[UIViewController userProfileViewController];
    userViewController = ProfileControllerModeEditing;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: userViewController animated:YES];
}
```

По нажатию на нее переходим на другой контроллер, в котором не вызывается метод viewWillAppear. Я просто в контроллере userViewController подписываюсь на observer в viewWillAppear. Получается такая ситуация, что когда я перехожу на этот контроллер и не вызывается метод viewWillAppear (в котором я подписываюсь на observer) при закрытии этого контроллера я отписываюсь от observer и получаю ошибку. Мне кажется проблема возникает где-то в стеке контроллеров, когда я из модального контороллера делаю pushViewController

2) При создании таблицы мне необходимо добавить только на первую ячейку (indexPath.row == 0) какой-либо объект, путь это будет UIView - какой-нибудь маленьких цветной квадратик ([cell addSubView:view]). При прокрутке ячейки перерисовываются и добавленный view появляется на нескольких ячейках (хотя я добавил его с условием indexPath.row == 0). Я читал что нежелательно добавлять в ячейку объект через addSubView:view, но как можно избежать этой проблемы, если необходимо создать объект другого класса и поместить на одну ячейку? (Пробовал if (!cell)). Буду признателен за ответы

UPDATE:

1)Проблема оказалась немного другой, не досмотрел цепочку вызовов.

**Что было:** Вызывалось модальное окно А, с этого модального окна делался pushViewController на контроллер В, который являлся контейнером и добавлял в этот контейнер класс С. Соотвественно в классе С и не вызывался метод viewWillAppear, в котором мне нужно было подписать на observer.

**Решение:**
 Вызываем следующий метод
 (BOOL)automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers {
         return NO;
     }

Теперь можно использовать методы viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear..

2) Просто использовать метод - (void)prepareForReuse {..} для удаления объекта с других ячеек, хотя не думаю что это оптимальное решение.

Comment: напишите минимальный пример показывающий вашу проблему с  viewWillAppear.

Comment: Я добавил небольшой пример, который, надеюсь, немного понятнее объясняет мою проблему

Comment: имелся ввиду проект, который можно запустить и дебажить проблему

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую вытащить эту проблему из большего проекта и прислать сюда, во всяком случае отпишусь если самому удасться исправить и понять причину

Comment: Проверьте цепочку ваших VC. Скорее всего, в одном или нескольких из них, где-то в методах типа `-viewWillApperar:`, `-viewDidDisappear:` вы не вызываете `super`. Также возможно, что какой-либо VC не был добавлен в стэк методом `-addChildViewController:` с последующим вызовом `-didMoveToParentViewController:`.

Comment: Кстати, в примере, я полагаю, должно быть что-то вроде `userViewController.mode = ProfileControllerModeEditing;`?

Comment: Для различия первой и всех остальных ячеек используйте различные идентификаторы в `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` и в `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`. Прямо тупо `@"zeroCellID"` и `@"allTheOtherCellsID"`.

Comment: Добавил решение в пост, если кому интересно